# Reading data from excel in python and making http requests

Tags: python, json, excel

I have an excel which contains multiple columns and rows. I am creating a dictionary for each row. I am adding this dictionary to a list of dictionaries(say list_of_dictionaries). The list of dictionaries is passed as JSON for the http requests. Now one of the column in the excel is a Boolean. When I create JSON using above steps, the Boolean is converted to a string.

The correct JSON should be `{"my_boolean": true }` but above steps result in `{"my_boolean":"true"}`.

What is the better way to do this?

Requests library converts the list to JSON.

```
request  = requests.get("https://myurl.com",JSON = list_of_dictionaries)
```

Comment: Have you tried reading excel using pandas, it trued to infer data type.

Comment: I am using pandas to read the excel.

Comment: true is different from True. If in the original dictionary it is true, then when u pass it to request it will use json.dumps which will convert it to "true". Make sure it is True in dictionary. Then only you will get true, not "true".

Comment: json.dumps({"my_boolean": "true"}) = {"my_boolean": "true"}; json.dumps({"my_boolean":True}) = {"my_boolean": true}

Answer (score 0):

One simple way is to iterate through lists, compares and replace them.

```
for each in list_of_dictionaries:
    if each["my_boolean"].lower() == "true":
        each["my_boolean"] = True
    elif each["my_boolean"].lower() == "false":
        each["my_boolean"] = False
    elif each["my_boolean"] == "":
        each["my_boolean"] = None
```

Comment: The JSON is created by the requests library. I am passing list_of_dictionaries as input to the requests. Please look above.

Comment: Requests library does not convert data type. It converts python dict object to a JSON object. Just iterate through the list and assign value as True, False, None. Request library will convert it to true, false, null. If you pass "true", "false", request library will consider it as a string and will not convert it to true, false